# Exports functions globally in CouchDB

Tags: module, couchdb, global, commonjs

Is there any possibility to set library function as globally in database, or across the server ? Or this is only possibile in one design document, and if I would like to have this function in other design document, I shoud to copy this function ?

In example:

path: {database}/_design/doc1

```
{
...
"MyGlobalLib" : "exports.getsum = function() { return 2 + 2; }",
...
}
```

path: {database}/_design/doc2

```
{
...
"shows" : {"anyshow": "function() { return require('MyGlobalLib').getsum(); }" },
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handlers (lists, shows, views, etc.) are per design document, but you can call them on any different view. This means every function is global and available just inside the database where is defined. It doesn't make sense redefine the same function in another design document. Imagine a design document like a namespace.

Comment: I think that too, these functions should be availiable at least on all database. But I have problem, how to call them ? As far I know, I should use for it require method from CommonJS, but when I tryied use "require('../designdoc2/doc/function').getme()" I had an error.

Comment: Please, read [Formatting with Show and List](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List).

Comment: Hmm, I haven't find anything useful about my problem.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't find anything useful about my problem. Can I write shared library in design docement 1, and use require in other design document i.e. _design/2, and in path pointing to other design document ? I know, that I have access to current design document, but did shared library can be accessed from different _design ? Just server-side ? I guess no, because I can't find a solution. I know, that I can use CouchApp and his macro, but I would like do it in pure CouchDB.

Comment: No you can't do that.